# Received so many downloading links – Is it possible to batch download?

Tags: internet

I have received an email with about 200 pictures downloading links from a hosting site. Is there any way I can batch download all of the pictures instead of click each downloading link? I guess the pictures were uploaded one by one.

Comment: Are these links image url? What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**If you're on *nix:**

Just copy and paste the URLs to a text file, so you have on on each line.

```
http://example.com/image1.jpg
http://example.com/image2.jpg
```

Save this as `urls.txt`

Then run `wget -i urls.txt`. wget will retrieve every URL in the file to the current directory.

**If you're on Windows:**

Get [wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) from the GnuWin32 project (download the "complete package, except sources" and run the installer). Create a text file like I instructed above and save it in the new folder as `urls.txt`. Then, hold shift and right click the folder and choose "Open a command prompt here". Then, in the command prompt, run the same command as above (`wget -i urls.txt`).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file which downloads the files with `wget`

In effect it becomes a script.

You would create a text file listing the URLs and precede each with `wget`, for example:

```
wget -nd http://example1.com/image1.jpg
wget -nd http://example2.com/image2.png
```

The `-nd` option makes sure that the directory structure of the source website is not duplicated and all files are downloaded into the current working directory.